# File upload with jQuery file upload plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Hi I have the following problem. I use **jQuery file upload plugin** and want to implement file uploader in one of my website pages. I am using the **[UI version](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)** so the thing is working, the files are uploaded but when i try to delete them i have an 404 error on the request. I am using POST request. The problem is that I get 404 header error and that is screwing the code. My page is responding with the right JSON data but the header is 404 I searched the whole [uploader class][3], but i can't find where the header is set and even if I comment that 404 line

`if (!$this->is_valid_file_object($file_name)) {
    return $this->header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}`

Nothing happens so I cant understand where in which javascript file or in the **[upload handler class](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php)** the headers go wrong and how to fix the problem.

So my ajax return is like follows:

> _method:DELETE
>   /my_domaing/some_page/uploadAction/file:action_test_file_3%20%281%29.doc
>
> POST 404 Not Found text/plain jquery.js:8706 Script 991 B 360 B 20 ms 20 ms

I think the problems comes from my framework cause in plain php I can upload and delete files. But when i open the page in my browser with that link I can see the JSON response which is:

```
{"file":{"name":"action_test_file_3.doc", "size":61440,
"url":"http:\/\/my_domain\/files\/action_test_file_3.doc",
"deleteUrl":"http:\/\/my_domain\/some_page\/uploadAction\/file:action_test_file_3.doc\/
_method:DELETE\/file:action_test_file_3.doc\/_method:DELETE","deleteType":"POST"}}
```

I don't know what I need to get so the file be deleted, but I know that the header information is gone wrong cause I can open it and see the information but the POST request sees the 404 error and just doesn't do nothing.

The framework I use have a .htaccess rewrite rule which is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|htc|txt|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|htm|html|
bmp|flv|xml|zip|plist|ipa|woff|ttf|svg|eot)|^design(.*)|^sks(.*)$ index.php
```

But I don't think the rule has anything to do with this upload. My framwork uses **Smarty**. I really can't find the way to solve the problem the uploading is working perfectly so why not the deleting. And I have write/delete permissions on the directory.

***I don't get any javascript errors and in my php log there are not errors regarding this page.***

*So I think the problem is with the header information and if it returns 404 the file is just not deleted that is all. But I can't understand where and how this is happening.*

So feel free to ask me anything but I can't send you a live demo cause it is a developer server, but I will do anything to try and resolve this problem cause I am struggling with it for almost 2 days. Any help is and will be appreciated!

Comment: Let's check if you are actually sending the request to the right page. Try putting `echo('Check me!'); exit(0);` at the beginning of the PHP code. Your Ajax call should return "Check me!".

Comment: Yes I am sending to the right page if i wasn't the upload wouldn't be working at all. So that's for sure not the problem and I said that I get the JSON response code which you can see there I just get the 404 error in the header information for the request.